# Quais as teclas de atalho no PHPStorm para remover os Namespaces que não estão em uso em uma Classe?

Tags: phpstorm

Qual é o atalho no `phpstorm` que limpa os namespaces que não estão em uso em uma classe, vi em uma video aula o professor falando de uma combinação de teclas e limpou automaticamente os namespaces use App.... etc, mas não falou quais eram.

```
use App\Contracts\UserRepositoryInterface;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repositories\UserFacebookRepository;
use Config;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use OAuth;
```

Abaixo:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use Config;
```

não estão em uso, como remover pelas teclas de atalho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Sim*** existe as teclas que são responsáveis em otimizar o seu código retirando os `namespaces` não utilizados:

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+**O**.

Existe uma diferença se o ***sistema operacional*** for `MAC OS X` as teclas são:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+**O**

***Referencias:***

- [PHP Namespaces and PSR Support in PhpStorm](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Namespaces+and+PSR+Support+in+PhpStorm)
- [Optimizing Imports](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Namespaces+and+PSR+Support+in+PhpStorm#PHPNamespacesandPSRSupportinPhpStorm-OptimizingImports)
- [Working with PSR-0 and PSR-4 Namespace Roots](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Namespaces+and+PSR+Support+in+PhpStorm#PHPNamespacesandPSRSupportinPhpStorm-WorkingwithPSR-0andPSR-4NamespaceRoots)